# Wordpress page doesnt load properly

Tags: php, wordpress

My webpage doesn't load as usual. The complete theme layout is abandoned. I used Hummingbird and smush to make the website load faster but during this process is started to load like described. I reset the settings of these plugins but its doesn't seem to help.

Anyone advice on what to do?

This is how the website is looking now

[image]

This is how it should look

[image: This is how it should look]

Comment: press **F12** and check what **css** is not loading

Answer (score 0):

Fairly sure you need to take a look into Hummingbirds settings. This tends to happen when plugins like that try to smush all the CSS into one giant file. (Combine/minify)

Sometimes you can combine but not minify, other times you can minify and not combine.

Tends to be more of an issue with premium themes and plugin vs custom builds.